# Find and replace certain text in a document with their HTML counterpart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scan a document using JavaScript and replace all occurrences of [x] with its HTML counterpart, such as  <b>[x] </b>, where x is a number. This is what I have so far, which does add the  tag around the target text, but as HTML entities, not actual HTML:

```
function walkText(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    node.data = node.data.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, '<b>[$1]</b>');
  }
  if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT") {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
walkText(document.body);
```

The end result is just the text  <b> wrapped around the text, and not actually bolding them. Does anyone know an efficient way to actually search for certain text in a long document and actually replace the target text with HTML?

Answer (score 0):

TextNode objects contain only text content without any HTML or XML markup.
So replace them is not so easy that people first saw.

```js
function walkText(node) {
  // if (node.nodeType == 3) {
  if (node instanceof Text) {
    if (!node.data.trim().length) {
      return;
    }
    // parentheses would reserve the splitters
    const parts = node.data.split(/(\d+)/).filter(Boolean);
    if (parts.length < 2) {
      return;
    }

    //
    // ─── Method 1. WRAP WITH SPAN ───────────────────────────────────────────
    //
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = parts
      .map(item => {
        // simple check again
        return /\d/.test(item) ? `<b>${item}</b>` : item;
      })
      .join('');
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);

    //
    // ─── METHOD 2. WITHOUT SPAN ──────────────────────────────────────
    //
    // const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    // parts
    //   .map(item => {
    //     if (/\d+/.test(item)) {
    //       const b = document.createElement('b');
    //       b.innerText = item;
    //       return b;
    //     } else {
    //       return document.createTextNode(item);
    //     }
    //   })
    //   .forEach(item => {
    //     frag.appendChild(item);
    //   });
    // node.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, node);
  }
  if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != 'SCRIPT') {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
walkText(document.body);
```

```html
<div>
  hello 113 world at 3
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to make the element bold, replace

```
 node.data = node.data.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, '<b>[$1]</b>');
```

with

```
node.style.fontWeight='bold';
```

If you want to replace the contents of the element with some other html, do this:

```
node.innerHTML = "<mytag>" + node.innerHTML + "</mytag>";
```

Comment: Could be a  big long sentence. That would bold the whole thing which is clearly not OP's intent

Comment: Yeah this either bolds or modifies the HTML of the entire text node. I'm looking to isolate just a particular text within a text node, and transform them into HTML.